# Parameters validation with Express using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I would like to validate http request parameters in Express (and express-param) using regular expressions.
This parameter must be a number with 11 digits at least.

Why `app.param('uid', /^[0-9]{11,}+$/);` returns an error?

And why `app.param('uid', /^[0-9]{11,}/);` don't works fine?
It blocks params like `1234567890c` and accepts `12345678901c` or `12345678901ca`.

Comment: Well, the latter doesn't specifiy that the string has to end after those 11 digits. So if there are at least 11 digits, anything can follow. What error do you get for the first one?

Comment: It returns error at compiling time. `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9]{11,}+$/: Nothing to repeat at new RegExp (unknown source)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two patterns are inconsistent. The first (which is an invalid regex) has an ending `$` specifying that the input must match your pattern up to the end of the string. The problem is you have a `+` after the numbers which causes it to be invalid as you specify the number of times it should repeat already with `{11,}`.

The second pattern drops both the `+` and the `$`. Dropping the `+` is perfect, however, when you drop the `$` you say that anything *after* the numbers can appear.

Try adding a `$` to the second pattern:

```
app.param('uid', /^[0-9]{11,}$/);
```